# What in essence are PCSOs? (Organizationally and career trajectory wise)

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, police

And where do they fit into the system of police? Are they aspiring police constables in training who will hopefully one day progress into full policedom?

Do they report under the met?

Comment: Please indicate the research you've done. Have you looked at the Wikipedia article, or any police websites?

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations in the title.

Comment: Obligatory: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aapEbnIOcE8

Comment: @NateEldredge lol

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/standard-powers-and-duties-of-police-community-support-officers-pcsos

Comment: The Wikipedia article on PCSOs is quite extensive and answers all aspects of your question.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_community_support_officer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What in essence are PCSOs?**

Police Community Support Officers (PCSO) are civilian employees (also known as police staff) of the relevant police force, a role created by [section 38](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2002/30/section/38?timeline=false) Police Reform Act 2002.

They may be designated with (i.e. authorised to use) any power or duty of a constable except those identified in [Part 1 of Schedule 3B](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2002/30/schedule/3B/part/1?timeline=false) and any or all of the various powers and duties found in [Schedule 3C](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2002/30/schedule/3C?timeline=false) (*far too many to repoduce here*).

**Where do they fit into the system of police?**

Each force area has its own requirements, priorities and demands, but for the [Metropolitan Police Service](https://www.met.police.uk/car/careers/met/pcso/pcso-overview/) (the Met) PCSO roles include:

> Safer Neighbourhood Teams – focussing on crime and antisocial behaviour within the community.
>
> Safer Transport Teams – focussing on over-ground transport, working with the public to ensure and reassure that our transport networks are safe.
>
> Roads Policing Teams – working alongside Traffic Officers, dealing with collision scenes, incidents and broken down vehicles.
>
> Reassurance Tasking Teams – visible presence on the roads, enforcing red routes and managing network disruption.
>
> Tunnel Team- focussing on keeping London’s Tunnel network operating at full capacity and dealing with associated issues.

**Are they aspiring police constables in training who will hopefully one day progress into full policedom?**

Some are, some are not. There is neither an expectation nor requirement to apply to be a constable.

**Do they report under the Met?**

Not all, as each police force has reporting responsibilities for its own employees.